# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Two clicks required for login instead of one

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am using the Form-based authentication and challenge handler (sample codes) in my App. The problem is, it is not authenticating users on a single click on the login button - I have to click two times. Why?

I have protected all adapter functions.

**My challenge handler** :

```
var myAppRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("myAppRealm");
myAppRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
     if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }
    var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');
    WL.Logger.debug("indicatorIdx =" + indicatorIdx);
    if (indicatorIdx >= 0){ return true; }  
    return false; 
};
myAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
    $.mobile.changePage("#landingPage" , { transition: "slide"});
    WL.Logger.debug("Login Again");
};

myAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback = function(response) {
    var isLoginFormResponse = myAppRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse(response);
    WL.Logger.debug("submitLoginFormCallback " + isLoginFormResponse + " responseText " + response.responseText);
    if (isLoginFormResponse){
        myAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(response);
    } else {
        myAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
    }
};
$('#logindone').bind('click', function () {
        var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
        var options = {};
            options.parameters = {
                j_username : $.trim($('#fldloginUserID').val().toLowerCase()),
                j_password : $.trim($('#fldloginUserPassword').val())
            };
            options.headers = {};
            myAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, myAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
    processLogin();
});
```

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<securityTests>
        <mobileSecurityTest name="myMobileSecurity">
            <testUser realm="myAppRealm"/>
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
        </mobileSecurityTest>       
        <customSecurityTest name="PushApplication-custom-securityTest">                             
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="PushAppRealm"/>   
        </customSecurityTest>       
        <customSecurityTest name="myAppSecurityTestCustom">                             
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="myAppRealm"/>   
        </customSecurityTest>       
        <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
            <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>    
<realms>
        <realm loginModule="StrongRC" name="myAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <!--<parameter name="login-page" value="login.html"/>-->
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="PushAppLoginModule" name="PushAppRealm">                                                
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.BasicAuthenticator</className>   
            <parameter name="basic-realm-name" value="PushAppRealm"/>                                                  
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="Console" name="WorklightConsole">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
        </realm>
</realms>
<loginModules>
         <loginModule name="PushAppLoginModule">
            <className>com.rc.services.RCAuthModule</className>
        </loginModule>      
        <loginModule name="StrongRC">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>      
        <loginModule name="Console">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
</loginModules>
```

**my processLogin() function**

```
function processLogin(userid,password){ 
    var userid = $("#fldloginUserID").val();
    var password = $("#fldloginUserPassword").val();    
    WL.Logger.debug("Authenticating user credentials...");
    var invocationData = {  adapter: "LDAPAdapter", procedure: "ValidateUsers", parameters: [userid, password]};    
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, { 
        onSuccess: checkUserAccountStatus,  
        onFailure: function(){  hideBusyIndicator();
            showPopUp(msg_en.LoginFailed_MsgTitle , msg_en.LoginFailed_MsgDescription_2);
        } ,timeout : 30000  });
}

function checkUserAccountStatus(response){
    WL.Logger.debug("Checking user account status...");
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.invocationResult.result);
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ); 
    if (!response ||!response.invocationResult || !response.invocationResult.result ||
            $xml.find("isUserValidated").text()=="false" ) { hideBusyIndicator();  
            showPopUp(msg_en.LoginFailed_MsgTitle, msg_en.LoginFailed_MsgDescription_2);
    else { getUserDetails(response.invocationResult.result); }  
}

function getUserDetails($xml){
 ...doing something over retrieved data from LDAP ,like saving in local var......
 ....
 ...then calling another adapter....
    if($xml.find("LDAPuserID").text() > 0){                 
            var invocationData = {adapter: "MQAdapter",procedure: "ListSummariesDetails", parameters: [$xml.find("LDAPuserID").text() ] };
            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                onSuccess: getSecretSuccessData_Callback,
                onFailure: function(){ hideBusyIndicator();
                    showPopUp(msg_en.SystemError_Title , msg_en.SystemError_Description);
                } ,timeout : 30000 });
        }   
}

function getSecretSuccessData_Callback(response){
...... now do something over retrived data
...let the user go in the main page of the App after login screen
    $.mobile.changePage("#mainPage" , { transition: "slide"});
}
```

The **ValidateUsers** and **ListSummariesDetails** adapter functions are **protected** using **myAppSecurityTestCustom** which is given above.

Comment: Does it happen also in preview, or only in emulator/simulator/device? which device? What is your Worklight version?

Comment: What does the call to processLogin() at the end of your click handler do?

Comment: @Idan, It happens in both preview and on device. I am using WL Consumer 5.0.6.

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter, the processLogin() is taking user ID & password and calling adapter functions. Once UserId/password is validated it lets user to go inside the app ( main page).

Comment: It sounds like you are making a second adapter call in the middle of the authentication for the first call. 

The call to processLogin() in your click handler, if it is making another adapter call, will trigger a second authentication because the authentication that you are in the middle of processing isn't complete yet.  It might be helpful to explain how authentication gets triggered in the first place.  (something somewhere make an adapter call...) and to provide the source of processLogin()

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter, yes true. processLogin() is making a cal to another adapter. However it is making call in the success call back function of first adapter call.....see my modified question and processLogin() code..... plz suggest. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered via a PMR the customer opened in IBM. They have since changed the implementation to using Adapter-based authentication as that is the authentication flow that fits their app structure. This question is somewhat outdated by now...

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your login page (landingPage) is visible when the app starts, and that the first time logindone gets clicked, there is no authentication in progress (yet).  This won't work the way you are expecting.

Make a different page the default page for your app.
Take the call to processLogin() out of your click handler.  I would also put the transition to mainPage in the success case of submitLoginFormCallback().

Now, put a call to WL.Client.login() in wlCommonInit(). 
(this will trigger authentication)  Put the call to processLogin() in the success callback for the call to WL.Client.login()

Comment: David, Thanks for suggestion, I'll definitely try this out and will update you tomorrow, hope it should work. Thanks

Comment: David,I tried this but its not working, it only works in browser but not on device! what else we can do? thanks

Comment: So it works with a single click in the browser?  Do you have a log cat from the device?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I was using IP Address for testing and DNS entry was present in the code, i.e. my URL was mydomain.com and IP is 123.123.123.123 , now if I built the application using 123.123.123.123 , I have to click the login button twice.

The solution I found was to add mydomain.com in my hosts / DNS server and after that I built the application for mydomain.com.

Worked perfectly for me.